# How does the generic off-topic close reason occur?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I occasionally see close review queue items pop up that have a completely generic Off-Topic close vote reason:

> off-topic: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

How does this happen?

Example from [a review that just came up for me](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/13591713):

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Flaggers - people who haven't yet earned the reputation needed to [vote to close](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) - don't get to enter a specific off-topic reason if none of the pre-defined ones fit. For them, the "other" option reads simply, "Blatantly off-topic", and does not prompt for a more nuanced description.

The goal here is to discourage the use of this for anything that might just be mildly annoying to someone, and avoid wasting the time of moderators and reviewers.

Obviously, if it *is* off-topic then you can vote to close and specify a reason. If it isn't obviously inappropriate, you can opt to leave the question open.

Comment: Ha, this is the first time that I've come across something that I can't see *because* I have rep (other than ads I guess...). Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff [Downvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2373/191410) any questions recently? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might also be seeing flags generated via my [Always Be Closing](https://stackapps.com/questions/4345/always-be-closing) userscript on stackapps.

The `OT` button (off topic) submits a reason similar to, but not exactly like, the reason you listed in your question...

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

I figure they're close enough that you wouldn't remember the difference between the two.